# parallax scrolling using jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I need to add auto scroll effect into following code. which is used in a wordpress site. when click on a menu need to focus on the following section.

```html
<section class="screen_shotz" style="display:block;">
<div class="light_box_wrap container">
 <div class="title ">
  <h2>SCREENSHOTS</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="tab_wrap wow bounceIn animated">
 
  <div class="light_box_tab col-md-6">
  
   <div class="light_box_inner driver">
   
    <div class="light_box_lay" id="driver">
    
     <h2>Driver App<!--<div class="fa fa-chevron-right light_box_arrow"></div>--></h2>
     
    
    </div>
   </div>
  
  </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: What did you try before?

Answer (score -1):

Please Try this

```
$("#menuid").click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".screen_shotz").offset().top
}, 2000); 
});
```

write inside the click if you want do any other operations

Comment: Please be more specific.